# An icon figure with actual figure side by side

Tags: floats

In a LaTeX book, I want an icon figure placed outside the regular text margin and an actual figure within text width. I need no caption or figure number for icon figure.

I have seen `\marginpar` commands and `minipage` inside the `figure` environment but both do not solve my issue.

How should I do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `:)` What have you tried with `\marginpar` and `minipage` so far? If you put together a [minimal (non-)working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), it will probably be a bit easier for us to help you out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `marginnote` package to put a note into the margin for a floating figure. For example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\marginnote{\includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{prerequis.png}}%
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Caption of actual figure}
\label{labelActualFigure}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-3]

\begin{figure}
\marginnote{\includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{prerequis.png}}%
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Caption of actual figure B}
\label{labelActualFigureB}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `\marginpar`, I tried

```
\marginpar{\includegraphics]{iconFigure}}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{actualFigure}
\caption{Caption of actual figure}
\label{labelActualFigure}
\end{figure}
```

Result: Actual figure is above the icon figure, although icon figure is outside the text margin (something which I want).

With minipage, I tried

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.1\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{iconFigure}
\caption{}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{actualFigure}
\caption{Caption of actual figure}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Result: Two figures are side by side, within the text margin, with their respective captions and numbers (Fig.1 and Fig. 2).

Comment: This isn't really an answer; you should edit your question to include this information.